# MDX: use generate to parse a hierarchy in search of a specific scenario

Tags: mdx

I created a hierarchy of the following structure:

```
[Contact Key].[Type].[Event Date Key].[Event Name]
```

I am looking to generate a set of all the `[Contact Key]`s having products `[Type]=FineArt` where the latest `[Event Date Key]` (LASTCHILD?) is `[Event Name]=Cancel`.

Here's my how I am understanding `GENERATE`, but it's not happening for me:

```
GENERATE (
   [Subscription Event].[Hierarchy 1].MEMBERS
  ,[Subscription Event].[Hierarchy 1].[Contact Key].&[FineArt].[Event Date Key].LASTCHILD.&[Cancel]
)
```

What's being done incorrectly?

Comment: Are the "FineArt" and "Cancel" some strings your would like to compare the [Type] and [Event Name] to?